# Как обойти заданную директорию?

Tags: c#

Изначально в программе задана директория:

```
private void Editor_Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(Application.StartupPath + @"\Data");
    // создаём структуру настроек с нуля
    // в дальнейшем надо загружать существующую
    var options = new DeviceOptions
    {
        vSync = false,
        windowed = true,
        windowedX = 1600,
        windowedY = 1200,
        vertexProcessingMode = 1
    };
    // инициализируем по-новому
    if (!MyDirect3D.InitializeWOpt(renderPanel, options))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Could not initialize Direct3D.", "Transedit", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Hand);
        base.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        MyGUI.splash_title = Localization.current_.namegame;
        MainForm.in_editor = true;
        MyDirect3D.вид_сверху = true;
        Road.качествоДороги = 5.0;
        this.ApplyLocalization();
        this.RefreshPanelSize(sender, e);
        this.toolBar_ButtonClick(this, new ToolBarButtonClickEventArgs(this.Edit_Button));
        Stop.неЗагружаемКартинки = true;
        this.Reset_World();
        this.без_игроков = new Игрок[0];
    }
}
```

Вот тут мне надо открыть ридими:

```
public void toolBar_ButtonClick(object sender, ToolBarButtonClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == this.Info)
    {
        Process.Start("notepad.exe", "Readme_Editor.txt");
    }
}
```

Как мне открыть это ридими, если оно не в папке `Data`, а в корне программы?
Либо как можно этот ридими запихать в папку `Data`?

Comment: `Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @".."))`

Comment: `Process.Start("Readme_Editor.txt");` - это откроет текстовый файл в том приложении, которое задано у пользователя

Answer (score 1):

```
Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
```